# Comparison test $\sum(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)/k$

Tags: real-analysis

How do you use the Comparison test to test if

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}k$$

is convergent?

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}k = \dfrac1{k\left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)} \leq \dfrac1{k^{3/2}}$$
Now conclude the convergence.